# Add Button in TabNavigator Header

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

i want to add minmun/maximum button on tabnavigator header.......how i could be possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- put the tab navigator and a button in a canvas
- set the X and Y of button Y=0 and X=tabnavigator.width - button-width-10
- on click of button use Resize function set HeightTo=0 and heightFrom= tabnavigator.width
  then play() the resize
- to restore heightFrom=0 and heightTo=previous size of navigator

then you got the illusion of minimizing ang maxizing the tab navigator.. please do add some more effects of your desire..

Hope this gives you a idea on it..

Answer (score 0):

Ive never heard of a tabNavigator header, but if you mean adding buttons to the tabs themselves, then theres an example and source code you could work from with [FlexLib SuperTabNavigator](http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/wiki/ComponentList)

Comment: ok you are right........i want to minimize the tab navigator........so u please suggest any good option

Answer (score 0):

Forget how it looks at first. Create a button that simply hides the TabNavigator. I'm sure there are plenty of tutorials out there on how to animate show/hide. Once you have that, move the button where you want it and style it as you wish.